# How to validate that user inputs only one comment for one file? MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, validation, if-statement

I have three tables which are books, user_comment and users. The table books saves book id and details of book and the table users saves user_id, username and other details of user. Alongside user_comment holds the username, comment and book_id that he/she has commented.

The problem behind this is, I want user be able to put only one comment per book (kind of like restriction!)

I am looking for that if statement where I can collabrate all these three tables.

comment.php

```
$_COOKIE['username']; 

INSERT INTO user_comment (book_id, username, comment) VALUES ($_POST['book_id'], $_POST['book_id'], $_POST['book_id']))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to make a `SELECT` to check if **username** and **book_id** exist, if it exist you make the `INSERT`, if not you send a text or what you want to show to the user...

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ...");
$total = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($total == 0){
  ...insert here...
}
```

*note: I'm using old version php query, you may have to change to mysqli if you are using newer version.*

Comment: Its says call to undefined function mysql_row_count()

Comment: my bad... the function is **mysql_num_rows**  [link](http://www.php.net/mysql_num_rows)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do here, is set the columns (user_id, book_id) as to be unique.

Go to **phpMyAdmin** or any other mysql client you are using and execute the following query

```
ALTER TABLE user_comments ADD UNIQUE (user_id, book_id);
```

Adding a unique index ensures that atmost one book_id, user_id pair can exist in the table. So even if you try to insert the same pair again, it won't get inserted into the table. This solves your problem of allowing just one comment to a user per book.

Comment: or leave the exiting primary key alone an add a unique index

Comment: @sanketh, Yes user_id and book_id are already unique keys. But it doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work ?" . Are you able to insert duplicate rows into the table ?

Comment: @user3517015, do you already have duplicate rows in your table. If so, try deleting them and then add the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on the (username, book_id) tuple. One way to add that:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_comment_UX1 ON user_comment (username, book_id);
```

Whenever an attempt is made to INSERT or UPDATE rows in the user_comment table that would violate the uniqueness of the (username,book_id) tuple, the MySQL will throw an error, rather than completing the operation.

If you already have rows that violate this uniqueness, then MySQL will not be able to create the index.

To identify the rows that are not unique:

```
SELECT book_id
     , username
     , COUNT(1)
  FROM user_comment
 GROUP BY book_id, username
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```